# Does a neighbourhood need to be a *connected* set?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, terminology

I have in my topology/ real analysis textbook the definition of neighbourhood of a point as an open set containing that point.

But isn't a neighbourhood necessarily a connected set? Wikipedia also says that "Intuitively speaking, a neighbourhood of a point is a set containing the point where you can move that point some amount without leaving the set." My complex analysis textbook also suggests that a neighbourhood of a point is a domain (defined as an open connected set) containing that point.

I've been googling, and none of the definitions that I've come across of "neighbourhood" have any connectedness condition. What am I missing?

Comment: In nice (aka. locally connected) spaces, every neighbourhood contains a connected neighbourhood. Since every superset of a neighbourhood is a neihbourhood, _in general_ neighbourhoods aren't connected. But in locally connected spaces, you can always choose a smaller connected neighbourhood when that is convenient.

Comment: Furthermore, in locally connected spaces every neighborhood contains an **open** connected neighborhood, i.e. a *domain* according to your complex analysis book.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you! So a neighbourhood need *not* be a connected set. Would you post this as an answer?

Comment: @Ryan That is not a connectedness condition. That means a neighbourhood "contains all sufficiently near points".

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh yes, on re-reading, you are right. Thank you again!

Comment: Ryan, Wikipedia isn't trying to say anything about connectedness in that statement (which is, by the way, only about *metric spaces*). Focus on the concept that a neighborhood of a point is a set having an open subset containing that point. Connectedness is a different concept, having to do with whether it's possible to "separate" the set into two "relatively open/relatively closed" subsets.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh one more question. My intro analysis textbook gives that a neighbourhood of a point c of $\mathbb R$ as an open interval that contains that point c. Isn't this definition incorrect then, since this definition institutes a connectedness condition?

Comment: Better to call it "non-standard" than incorrect, but it is certainly not the usual definition. Terminology has developed over time; earlier texts especially may use the same terms in very different ways.

Comment: @dfeuer Thank you for your answer to my last question! Btw yes, I've seen the definition you gave in your first comment above, however I will use the slightly different one that my current textbook is using.

Comment: The usual term for what your book is calling "a neighborhood of $p$" is "an open interval about $p$", which isn't really much longer.

Comment: @dfeuer Sorry I don't understand what you mean by "which isn't really much longer"? And you're referrring to the definition I gave above that contains the word "interval", right? Meaning, to make the last definition consistent with the very first definition I gave above, I should it to "A neighbourhood of a point $c$ of $\mathbb R$ is an open interval or union of open intervals that contains that point c",  correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neighbourhoods need not be connected, and in general aren't (any superset of a neighbourhood of a point $p$ is also a neighbourhood of $p$, adding some arbitrary points to a connected set tends to result in a disconnected set).

However, in locally connected spaces (and the spaces used in analysis mostly are locally connected [locally path-connected even]), every point has a neighbourhood basis of (open) connected neighbourhoods, so one can often assume that a neighbourhood is connected in proofs (when one wants to prove something about arbitrarily small neighbourhoods, not when one wants to prove something about *all* [or even all sufficiently small] neighbourhoods) if that is convenient.